# More than one badge on a cell - Angular Calendar

Tags: angular, angular-calendar

I am using Angular Calendar https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar and i want to have more than one badge per cell, each badge in a counter for a different type of event. There is different types of events (using the meta property in event).
I am having a difficult time with the counter used for the events of a day.

This is the result i want to have.

[image: result i want]

**EDIT** : here's what i have tried

I used this custom template of the calendar cell to add the badges.

```
<ng-template #customCellTemplate let-day="day" let-locale="locale">
  <div class="cal-cell-top">
    <span style="background-color: grey" class="cal-day-badge" *ngIf="day.badgeTotal > 0">{{ day.badgeTotal }}</span>
    <span class="cal-day-number">{{ day.date | calendarDate:'monthViewDayNumber':locale }}</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="cal-day-badge" *ngIf="day.badgeTotal > 0">{{countErrors()}}</span>
    <span style="background-color: green" class="cal-day-badge" *ngIf="day.badgeTotal > 0">{{ countSuccesses() }}</span>
    <span style="background-color: orange" class="cal-day-badge" *ngIf="day.badgeTotal > 0">{{ countWarnings() }}</span>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

The three functions `countErrors()` `countWarnings()` and `countSuccesses()` count the number of events of the same type ( error or success or warning ).

The type of event is specified with the `meta` property :

```
{
  start: subDays(startOfDay(new Date()), 1),
  end: addDays(new Date(), 1),
  title: 'A 3 day event',
  color: colors.red,
  actions: this.actions,
  allDay: true,
  resizable: {
    beforeStart: true,
    afterEnd: true
  },
  draggable: true,
  meta : {
    type : 0
  }
},
```

When i run this, this is what i get :

[image: result i have]

I think one count was done for the first day, and all the other days got this same result.

**EDIT** : here's the function i call inside the template

```
countErrors(): number {
let count = 0;
this.events.filter(event => {
  if (event.meta.type === 0) {
    count++;
  }
})
return count;
}
```

The three functions are same. The only difference is the `if` condition : changing the event type 0 1 2.

Comment: what have you tried doing so far? any code you can include in the question?

Comment: Hello, please introduce yourself to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and correct your question.

Comment: @jmdavalos I am working on it currently. It didnt work like is should but i will edit my question and add it.

Comment: @jmdavalos code and result added in question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I came back just to say that the thing i was looking for had already an example in the Angular Calendar demo as the **Group month view events**.
See here : https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/group-month-view-events
I still had to custom the cell template using the provided css :

```html
<ng-template #customCellTemplate let-day="day" let-locale="locale">
  <div class="cal-cell-top">
    <span class="cal-day-badge" *ngIf="day.badgeTotal > 0">{{ day.badgeTotal }}</span>
    <span class="cal-day-number">{{ day.date | calendarDate:'monthViewDayNumber':locale }}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cell-totals">
    <span
      *ngFor="let group of day.eventGroups"
      class="badge badge-{{ group[0] }}">
      {{ group[1].length }}
    </span>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

And then i passed this customized template like :

```html
<mwl-calendar-month-view
    *ngSwitchCase="'month'"
    [viewDate]="viewDate"
    [events]="events"
    [cellTemplate]="customCellTemplate"
    (beforeViewRender)="beforeMonthViewRender($event)"
    [activeDayIsOpen]="true">
  </mwl-calendar-month-view>
```

And it's being displayed like :
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEm6M.png)